# Liferay DXP 7.2 listeners failed to start (clean version)

Tags: java, environment-variables, liferay, windows-server-2016, liferay-7

**Liferay DXP 7.2** is failed to start (clean version) with **OpenJDK**. Not using any IDE, it's Windows Server 2016 version (don't think any issue will be there with server edition) just started the startup.bat under `E:\PROJECT_NAME\liferay-dxp-tomcat-7.2.10.1-sp1-slim-20191009103614075\liferay-dxp-7.2.10.1-sp1\tomcat-9.0.17\bin`. Checked with Environment Variables `(JAVA_HOME:C:\openjdk-13.0.1_windows-x64_bin\jdk-13.0.1)`. It looks like any dependency or configuration is missing. Help needed.

````
22-Nov-2019 09:43:37.490 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.load Server initialization in [1,281] milliseconds
Loading jar:file:/E:/PROJECT_NAME/liferay-dxp-tomcat-7.2.10.1-sp1-slim-20191009103614075/liferay-dxp-7.2.10.1-sp1/tomcat-9.0.17/webapps/ROOT/WEB-INF/lib/portal-impl.jar!/system.properties
22-Nov-2019 09:43:40.912 SEVERE [main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart Error configuring application listener of class [com.liferay.portal.spring.context.PortalContextLoaderListener]
 java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
        at com.liferay.petra.reflect.ReflectionUtil.<clinit>(ReflectionUtil.java:162)
        at com.liferay.portal.spring.context.PortalContextLoaderListener.<clinit>(PortalContextLoaderListener.java:460)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstanceWithCaller(Constructor.java:500)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:481)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.newInstance(DefaultInstanceManager.java:151)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4604)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5150)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:713)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:690)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:695)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptor(HostConfig.java:631)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployDescriptor.run(HostConfig.java:1832)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:515)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:118)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptors(HostConfig.java:526)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployApps(HostConfig.java:425)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.start(HostConfig.java:1577)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.lifecycleEvent(HostConfig.java:309)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:123)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.setStateInternal(LifecycleBase.java:424)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.setState(LifecycleBase.java:367)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:929)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:831)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1377)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1367)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:140)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:902)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:262)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:423)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:928)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:634)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:567)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:350)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:492)
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchFieldException: modifiers
        at java.base/java.lang.Class.getDeclaredField(Class.java:2412)
        at com.liferay.petra.reflect.ReflectionUtil.<clinit>(ReflectionUtil.java:157)
        ... 48 more```
````

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you look at the [Liferay DXP compatibility matrix](https://web.liferay.com/services/support/compatibility-matrix), you'll discover that Java 13 is not on there - it's only the LTS versions. Run with a compatible version to eliminate this problem. Note that only the TCK-certified OpenJDK builds are supported, you might want to validate this on top of the version.

Comment: Yes. I used JDK8 and it's worked for me, Thanks. Also, do you have any idea regarding TCK-certified OpenJDK? I read a few articles but still not found what OpenJDK version/build is TCK certified which will be compatible with Liferay DXP. As per Liferay DXP compatibility matrix, All Java Technical Compatibility Kit
(TCK) compliant builds of Java 11 and Java 8 should be ok.

Comment: Hi @AritraDB - you should find the TCK information with your choice of OpenJDK (if your JDK is certified, that is). Also, good to know that it worked for you - consider accepting the answer as it solved your problem

Answer (score 0):

The error is due to incompatible JDK setup. So you need to change to compatible JDK.
Ex: JDK8 works well for liferay-ce-portal-tomcat-7.2.1-ga2.

In Windows:
Set JAVA_HOME to JDK folder path and PATH to to JDK/bin folder path.
Restart tomcat by opening new command line window it should work.